# Pulling Data from SQL Server pushes date backward one day. How to resolve?

Tags: sql-server

I am using R's odbc package to pull data from a SQL server DB. The data is private, but my queries looks something like this

```
select
  *
from
  tbl
where
 [some date] >= '2019-01-01'
```

but when I receive the data, `some.date` contains values like "2018-12-31" which doesn't make any sense. R's `tbl(conn, tbl)` tells me that `[some date]` is of date type not datetime type. But not sure if `tbl()` changes the type.

Under what circumstance does this happen? where the pulled date is goes back one day before.

Also, I tried changing the timezone on my machine to match that of what's in the Docker, but I can't replicate the error.

Basically, the error doesn't occur on my machine but only occurs when I run it in a docker container.

Not sure if the issue is to do with R.

I tried a few things but can't get to the bottom of them.

Just wondering if there are other avenues to explore e.g. does the SQL server have time settings etc, or bugs in R's odbc library etc.

Comment: *"Under what circumstance does this happen?"* it wouldn't. As a date and time data type or as a string based data type `2018-12-31` has a value **lower** than `2019-01-01`. See in this fiddle that all columns have the value `NULL`: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a32ed22a1f176b093eb7a4c956648bed). There's something you aren't telling us here.

Comment: *Perhaps* at a best guess, your column is actually a `datetime` and you are passing `2018-12-31` *not* `'2018-12-31'`. The former would be parsed as an integer expression, resulting in `1975`. That would then be converted to a `datetime`, which is `1905-05-30`, which **is** less that `2018-12-31`.

Comment: Good theory. But I checked the date is passed correctly and is quoted.

Comment: Then, like i stated in my original comment, there's something you're not telling us. You need to take the time to make a [mre].